# Is there a way can view real process cmdline on linux?

Tags: linux, security

Here is a simple code to fake process name and cmdline on linux:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NewName "bash"
#define ProcNameMaxLen 16

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int oldlen = strlen(*argv);
    char procname[ProcNameMaxLen];
    memset(*argv, 0, oldlen);
    memccpy(*argv, NewName, 0, oldlen); //modify cmdline
    memccpy(procname, NewName, 0, ProcNameMaxLen);
    prctl(PR_SET_NAME, procname); //modify procname
    sleep(60);
    return 0;
}
```

After run this code I can't view real name by ps,

but something can find in /proc/xxx/exe and /proc/xxx/environ, but so cumbersome.

is there a good way can view real information with all process?

I think this is a big security problem because i usually check process by ps on my server.

---

way 1: lsof -d txt

Wait more answer...

Answer (score 1):

[`lsof`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/lsof/) will tell you the original executable name as it is one of the open files of the malicious process. You can inspect a number of processes using the `-p` option, or query a single user with the `-u` option.

Comment: Thank you! But this is not a good way, get information with lsof every process will cost so many time.